# Remove white line between html table td's

Tags: html, css, html-email

I'm creating an HTML email template and have finally (after hours of frustration finding more blockers of how dated HTML technology is) got a design I like. I've removed the images I'll actually use, so apologise for the gross photos. But I'm trying to remove the white cell line between two `td`'s. I've removed `cell-padding` and `cell-spacing`, thinking that it would have a global effect on the table. But I am wrong. I've also used it on each `td`, but still no joy, any help will be appreciated.

P.S, thanks Gmail, for making the markup pretty ugly to look at and having to use inline style

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:300,400" rel="stylesheet">

  <style type="text/css">
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    table {
      width: 325px !important;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    #backgroundContent {
      height: 585px;
    }
    
    #buttonContainer {
      right: 1%;
    }
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:400px !important; max-width:450px !important; margin: 0 auto;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="backgroundContent" colspan="2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="text-align: center; width: 100%; height: 515px; background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/vV22b3P/testesttest.png); background-size: cover; background-position: 40% 0%;">
          <div id="leftContent" style="width: 50%; height: inherit; float: left; position: relative;">
            <p style="position: absolute; width: 90%; padding: 280px 0 0 0; margin: 0 auto; z-index: 10; text-align: left; margin-left: 12%; color: #ffffff; font-family: Nunito; font-weight: 300; font-size: 14px;">
              cursus a congue at, pharetra vel justo. Maecenas eget elit id nulla lobortis vestibulum eget fermentum nisi. Sed et tortor nunc. Proin id ornare dui. In risus arcu, aliquam et vulputate placerat, tempor ut elit. In ac placerat velit. Aliquam turpis dui,
              lobortis ut consequat et, cursus vel
            </p>
          </div>
          <div id="rightContent" style="width: 50%; height: inherit; float: left; position: relative;">
            <div id="buttonContainer" style="display: flex; position: absolute; height: 30%; width: 85%; padding: 320px 0px 0 0;">
              <ul style="list-style: none; text-decoration: none; text-align: center;">
                <li style="background-color: transparent; width: 70%; padding: 15px; margin-bottom: 8%; border: 1px solid #ffffff; border-radius: 5px; text-transform: uppercase; font-family: Nunito; font-size: 12px; color: #ffffff;">
                  <a href="https://www.google.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; cursor: pointer;">Mauris sit</a>
                </li>
                <li style="background-color: transparent; width: 70%; padding: 15px; margin-bottom: 8%; border: 1px solid #ffffff; border-radius: 5px; text-transform: uppercase; font-family: Nunito; font-size: 12px; color: #ffffff;">
                  <a href="*|CENTRE_NUMBER|*" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; cursor: pointer;">Mauris sit amet</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="background-color: #114496">
          <p style="float: right; text-align: right; margin-right: 25px; font-family: Nunito; font-size: 12px; color: #ffffff;">
            Mauris sit amet<br>Mauris sit amet
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There is too much in your snippet to see, shorten it down to what is necessary. [mcve]

Comment: See new snippet

Comment: Side note, you have an errant `}` at the start of your CSS

Comment: Try [border-collapse](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_border-collapse.asp)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to get rid of the white line with some CSS trickery. On the bottom `td`, I added:

```
margin-top: -1px;
display: inline-block;
width: 100%;
```

See working snippet:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title></title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:300,400" rel="stylesheet">

  <style type="text/css">
  }
  @media only screen and (max-width: 400px) {
    table {
      width: 325px !important;
      margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    #backgroundContent {
      height: 585px;
    }
    
    #buttonContainer {
      right: 1%;
    }
  }
  </style>
</head>

<body>

  <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="width:400px !important; max-width:450px !important; margin: 0 auto;">
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td id="backgroundContent" colspan="2" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="text-align: center; width: 100%; height: 515px; background-image: url(https://i.ibb.co/vV22b3P/testesttest.png); background-size: cover; background-position: 40% 0%;">
          <div id="leftContent" style="width: 50%; height: inherit; float: left; position: relative;">
            <p style="position: absolute; width: 90%; padding: 280px 0 0 0; margin: 0 auto; z-index: 10; text-align: left; margin-left: 12%; color: #ffffff; font-family: Nunito; font-weight: 300; font-size: 14px;">
              cursus a congue at, pharetra vel justo. Maecenas eget elit id nulla lobortis vestibulum eget fermentum nisi. Sed et tortor nunc. Proin id ornare dui. In risus arcu, aliquam et vulputate placerat, tempor ut elit. In ac placerat velit. Aliquam turpis dui,
              lobortis ut consequat et, cursus vel
            </p>
          </div>
          <div id="rightContent" style="width: 50%; height: inherit; float: left; position: relative;">
            <div id="buttonContainer" style="display: flex; position: absolute; height: 30%; width: 85%; padding: 320px 0px 0 0;">
              <ul style="list-style: none; text-decoration: none; text-align: center;">
                <li style="background-color: transparent; width: 70%; padding: 15px; margin-bottom: 8%; border: 1px solid #ffffff; border-radius: 5px; text-transform: uppercase; font-family: Nunito; font-size: 12px; color: #ffffff;">
                  <a href="https://www.google.com" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; cursor: pointer;">Mauris sit</a>
                </li>
                <li style="background-color: transparent; width: 70%; padding: 15px; margin-bottom: 8%; border: 1px solid #ffffff; border-radius: 5px; text-transform: uppercase; font-family: Nunito; font-size: 12px; color: #ffffff;">
                  <a href="*|CENTRE_NUMBER|*" style="text-decoration: none; color: #ffffff; cursor: pointer;">Mauris sit amet</a>
                </li>
              </ul>
            </div>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
        <td cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="background-color: #114496;margin-top: -1px;display: inline-block;width: 100%;">
          <p style="float: right; text-align: right; margin-right: 25px; font-family: Nunito; font-size: 12px; color: #ffffff;">
            Mauris sit amet<br>Mauris sit amet
          </p>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This solution may be problematic for gmail clients. Negative margins aren't always supported by gmail. See this article for more info - https://www.emailonacid.com/blog/article/email-development/12_things_you_must_know_when_developing_for_gmail_and_gmail_mobile_apps-2/

Comment: I have the same problem, but I fixed just adding border-collapse: collapse; for the tables

Answer (score 0):

I've had this problem in html emails viewed in Outlook on Windows desktop machines. If that is your problem, you can add this snippet before the closing

`<!--[if gte mso 12]><p style="font-size:12px;line-height:12px;>&nbsp;</p><![endif]-->`

Or try this: change background-image property on your `<td id="backgroundContent">`  to simply background: #114496 url(https://i.ibb.co/vV22b3P/testesttest.png);